# CKEditor WYSIWYG and Video Filter

Tags: wysiwyg

Drupal 7. WYSIWYG module, CKEditor as chosen library, Video Filter module.

When I manually type in the video filter code, it works. When I add the video filter button to the toolbar for my CKEditor profile, it works. But when I go to enter content and I click the video filter button in the CKEditor toolbar, it opens a new window and attempts to access a page that doesn't exist on my site, giving me the error `The requested page "/video_filter/dashboard/wysiwyg_ckeditor" could not be found.` Googling the error is unhelpful.

Comment: It started working after I disabled a number of other modules, such as Media, Media Youtube, and Video.

Comment: On a side note, I opened an issue a while ago on video_filter's ckeditor plugin, it has a patch fix for the youtube autoplay functionality http://drupal.org/node/1430680. (Worth noting because I see you used Media Youtube)

Comment: Thanks! I actually wasn't using Media YouTube anymore and that's why I disabled it, but it is definitely an issue that the maintainer should look at.